Why is this not adding?
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double q,r,s;
    printf("ENTER 2 NUMBERS");
    scanf("%2lf,%2lf", &q, &r);
    s=r+q;
    printf("THE ADDITION IS %2lf", s);
    return 0;
}

The output kept coming 1 when I wrote 1 and 3

Did you type 1, 3<ENTER> for input (with or without space, but with comma)? Suggestion: do if (scanf("%2lf,%2lf", &q, &r) != 2) { fprintf(stderr, "input error\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } ... remember to #include <stdlib.h>

FYI: scanf() wasn't desinged for user input. For toy programs, and, to a lesser extent, for learning exercises, it can serve the purpose. For "real programming" always prefer fgets() for user input.

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the problem. Your description "when I wrote 1 and 3" is not a sufficient description of the input, because you did not specify with which characters these two numbers are separated (e.g. with a space, comma or newline character). In this case, this distinction is very important. Please [edit] the question to fix this.

A thing to add besides the already given answers: You don't do any error checking at all for scanf(). If the user doesn't enter the numbers in the format, then r and q are still completely uninitialized and will get added together and saved in s. Initialize your variables sanely. Check for errors.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double q = 0, r = 0, s = 0;
    printf("ENTER 2 NUMBERS\n");
    if (scanf("%2lf,%2lf", &q, &r) != 2) {
       printf("Didn't enter number in needed format: num1,num2\n");
       return 0;
    }
    s = r + q;
    printf("THE ADDITION IS %2lf", s);
    return 0;
}

ENTER 2 NUMBERS
1,3
THE ADDITION IS 4.000000


Minor: I'd go with "%2lf ,%2lf" to allow optional white-space before the comma like 1 ,3.

Your scanf has a comma (,) in the format string, so you need to input your numbers with it (e.g. 1,1 and then Enter). If you provide your input like that, you'll get the expected output.

The problem is that you have a comma between the "%2lf,%2lf".
scanf essentially takes in a string of a certain format and then finds and stores in the datatype you have asked it. To do this it requires the string to be in a specific format. For example, if I have scanf(":%i:"), my string must be in a format with a : + integer + :.
When reading from the console however I presume your input for 1 and 3 is something like 1 3 which does not meet the format required by scanf because there is a space in between and not a comma.
To fix this you can replace the comma with a space or change your input such that it matches the required format of 1,3. By changing your code to:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double q,r,s;
    printf("ENTER 2 NUMBERS");
    scanf("%2lf %2lf", &q, &r);
    s=r+q;
    printf("THE ADDITION IS %2lf", s);
    return 0;
}


@WeatherVane I will edit that out I completely forgot about that, it's meant to be an example not real code to use. Thanks anyways

Edited it out and replaced it with ':'
